# domain settings in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

i have a live web app on azure with settings

[image]

with several host-names assigned to the site as below

[image]

As a change of requirements , i want the domain.net to be the parent domain where the root directory of my app points to, and not domian.co.uk

basically as shown below
[image]

As this is a live website, i want to achieve this with minimum downtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have added more than one custom domains to your web app, all the domains can be used to access your website, even only one is shown in the overview page.

If you want to use only one custom domain, you can remove the others. Or you can set a redirect rule for other domains at the DNS.

Comment: If you’re Microsoft partner, I find a free channel to solve azure queries: aka.ms/devchat. They support online chat and email.